# How to display data which the data is inside node child in fragment?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, fragment

My coding to display all data in **Fragment**:-

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Advertisement").child("tuitionPackages").child("0");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {

                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                String academicLevel,packageStatus,price,subjects;

                if (map.get("packageStatus") != null) {
                    packageStatus = map.get("packageStatus").toString();
                    mPackageType.setText(packageStatus);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }

    });
```

My database:-

[image]

My output to display the tuition packages:-

[image]

Comment: The question statement is a bit unclear, do you want to display the data that is inside the node that you've selected in your database image?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Yes, I want to display the tuitionPackages inside my Fragment...

Comment: >there are two scenario AFAIK you have fetch the data and send it to fragment

Create an xml and give each view a unique id and assign each value to it's corresponding Advertisement attribute

And the second one is you may require a way to fetch data here on basis of advertisment id. Fetch it and display as i suggest above.

Comment: @XarEAhmer, sorry, I dont really get it. Can you please some coding example?

Comment: first add your activity code from where you pass this fragment and the layout and full code file of current fragment then we will be able to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @XarEAhmer I am using 1 fragment layout only...

Comment: @XarEAhmer AFAIK means?

Comment: As far as I know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181921/discussion-between-daisy-and-xar-e-ahmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code to get data from your firebase database, then you can use that data to complete your fields in fragment.

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Advertisement").child(ID1).child(ID2).child("tuitionPackages");

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       String acadLvl = dataSnapshot.child("academicLevel").getValue(String.class);
                       String packStatus = dataSnapshot.child("packageStatus").getValue(String.class);
                       int price = dataSnapshot.child("price").getValue(Integer.class);
                       String sub = dataSnapshot.child("subjects").getValue(String.class);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

In this code `ID1` and `ID2` are the strings that I can see in your database image under node `Advertisement`.

Comment: @Daisy why is that, what is the problem?

Comment: The data did not display in my fragment

Comment: @Adda do mark the answer as correct and vote it up. This helps future SO readers with similar question, and I would appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Add your root element").child("tuitionPackages").child("0");

String academicLevel,packageStatus,price,subjects;

            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        if (map.get("academicLevel") != null) {
                            academicLevel = map.get("academicLevel").toString();
                            textView.setText(academicLevel);
                        }

                        if (map.get("packageStatus") != null) {
                            packageStatus = map.get("packageStatus").toString();
                            textView1.setText(packageStatus);
                        }

                        if (map.get("price") != null) {
                            price = map.get("price").toString();
                            textView2.setText(price);
                        }

                        if (map.get("subjects") != null) {
                            subjects = map.get("subjects").toString();
                            textView3.setText(subjects);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }

            });
```

Hope It's help full.

Comment: I will try, 1 minutes :D But why there is "passcode"?

Comment: add root and subroot element.

Comment: Ohh I see, 5 minutes, I will try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181924/discussion-between-daisy-and-chetan-mahajan).